# trouble understanding an exercise

Tags: sorting, scheme, racket

```
;; sort : list-of-numbers  ->  list-of-numbers (sorted)
;; to create a list of numbers with the same numbers as
;; alon sorted in descending order
(define (sorts alon)
  (cond
    [(empty? alon) empty]
    [(cons? alon) (insert (first alon) (sorts (rest alon)))]))

(check-expect (sorts (list 3 5 6 7)) (list 7 6 5 3))
```

An exercise problem that says using the above develop a version of quick-sort if the length of the input is below some threshold

I don't quite sure understand this problem or what they want the output to be. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't much left to do. If I understand correctly, you should have the option of sorting by two different algorithms: if the input lists' length is below a certain number, use `quicksort`, otherwise use the `sorts` procedure you just defined above. Either way, the expected output is a sorted list of numbers:

```
(define (my-sort alon threshold)
  (if (< (length alon) threshold)
      (quicksort alon)
      (sorts alon)))
```

In the question you state:

> using the above develop a version of quick-sort

Although it *is* possible to write `quicksort` in terms of `insert` (just for the heck of it), it's rather pointless, because anyway you have to partition the list (say, using `filter`) before being able to use `insert`, which simply ends up calling `cons` (in the second condition of `insert`):

```
(define (quicksort alon)
  (if (empty? alon)
      empty
      (append (quicksort (filter (lambda (x)
                                   (< x (first alon)))
                                 (rest alon)))
              (insert (first alon)
                      (quicksort (filter (lambda (x)
                                           (>= x (first alon)))
                                         (rest alon)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still kinda don't get it. What was the point of designing a quicksort when you could have just used the function insert?

Comment: @Josh I believe the point of the exercise is showing that for certain list lengths a sorting algorithm might be faster than other, and you should compare the relative durations. Other than that, using `insert` for implementing `quicksort` _is_ rather pointless. I updated my answer showing it